# Change notification tune in notification channel settings

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-settings

I'm following this guide to configure my NotificationChannels https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels.html#java

But when I open the settings screen with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, myNotificationChannel.getId());
startActivity(intent);
```

There is no tune preference. I can only turn On/Off the sound. Do I need some additional configuration of my channel, or is it impossible to set custom tune of notification?(I know that I can play the tune manually when notification pops up, but I really don't like this solution)

Channel code:

```
public String createChannel() {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(INCOMING_CHAT_CHANNEL_ID, INCOMING_CHAT_CHANNEL_TITLE,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription(INCOMING_CHAT_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);

        getNotificationManager().createNotificationChannel(channel);
        return channel.getId();
    }
```

And then I use returned channel Id:

Answer (score 0):

`Notification sound` setting will only appear for `higher priority` notifications.

Try to change your `Channel behaviour` to first (Make sound and pop up screen) or second (Make sound) option.

Please try to post the code where you are creating the Notification channel.

Comment: I have added code where I create Notification channel. It has IMPORTANCE_HIGH.

Comment: @Danil.B Your code seems fine and I have tested it on the emulator (API 28 and Q). There may be some device specific issue. Please tell me your device details like Manufacturer, Model, Android version, etc. You can also verify by checking the Notification channel settings from other apps.


If _Sound setting_ is not available for other apps also then, there may be some issue with your device.